# php date stripping, covert one format to another

Tags: php

Evening all I always struggle with moving dates between one format and another. This is probably really simple but I am struggling to find the answer on the forums.

I have this date

```
$date = "2013-08-12 00:00";
```

And I want to echo it out like this

```
12th Aug 2013
```

Can someone help please

Comment: `echo date('jS M Y', strtotime($date));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`date`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [`strtotime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

```
$date = "2013-08-12 00:00";
$newDate = date('jS M Y', strtotime($date));
```

Comment: perfect new it was simple just counld not for the life of me work itt out